# Need help writing code to move specific Data from one sheet to another in Excel

Tags: database, vba, excel, spreadsheet, helper

Essentially I need to move data from one sheet to another in Excel. I have attached photos of the data sheet (that I need to pull data from) and the destination sheet(that I need to post the data to). I need to write a code to read the sheet, and create a new row for each activity(cleaning, mopping, scrubbing, wiping, etc) with the correct # of hours they spent on each, how many units they completed, their name, and the year. I have attached a photo of a few lines that I completed manually, but if I could automate the process it would be a lot easier. Thanks so much for any help you can offer :)

[Source and Destination Forms, side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrcY2.png)

Comment: This is one of the most common asks here. Have you done any research? :)

Comment: Yes I have, I cannot seem to find out how to get a new row for each activity :(

Comment: If you post a snippet of what you have, it will be easier to determine where you are having issues.

Comment: I currently do not have any code written :( I do not even know where to start. The data that I transferred over I did manually

Comment: Does each employee get their own sheet?

Comment: No they do not, there are multiple forms similar to the one in the photo that I posted (each with a different employee and his or her data). After all the data from "Christopher Robbin's" form is entered, the next employee's data gets added underneath.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Any help I could get/ pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is not the cleanest code that I've ever done, but I believe it will fill out the parts of it that I understand and you can fill in the rest.

Since the employees are all on the same sheet underneath one another, it loops from i down to the bottom of the sheet. It checks for "PP" in the cell text and if it finds it, it will start checking that row for units/hours to transfer. If the type on that row has no error, it will copy the data for that type over. It repeats this for each type.

If there is no "PP" in the cell text on sheet one, then it will alternatively check for "Employee" name so that it knows whose name to copy onto sheet two for the following entries.

Now the code is really ugly because I have it continually specify each cell to grab the values from it. This was the quickest way for me to grab everything you list on your first sheet while making this easily update-able by you in the future.

```
Sub Report()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim row_current As Long
    Dim employee_name_row As Long: employee_name_row = 1

    For i = 1 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        If InStr(ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2, "PP") > 0 Then

            'getting row to use on sheet 2
            row_current = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

            If Not IsError(ws1.Cells(i, "D")) Then  'Cleaning

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, units, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "B").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "E").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "B").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If
            If Not IsError(ws1.Cells(i, "G")) Then  'Mopping

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, units, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "E").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "E").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "F").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "E").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If
            If Not IsError(ws1.Cells(i, "J")) Then  'Scrubbing

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, units, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "H").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "E").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "H").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If
            If Not IsError(ws1.Cells(i, "M")) Then  'Wiping

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, units, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "K").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "E").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "L").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "K").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If
            If Len(ws1.Cells(i, "N")) > 0 Then  'Jumping

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "N").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "N").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If
            If Len(ws1.Cells(i, "O")) > 0 Then  'Swimming

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "O").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "O").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If
            If Len(ws1.Cells(i, "P")) > 0 Then  'Other

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "P").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "P").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If
            If Len(ws1.Cells(i, "Q")) > 0 Then  'Computer Probs

                'period, name
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "A").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "B").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "B").Value2

                'task, hours
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "C").Value2 = ws1.Cells(3, "Q").Value2
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "F").Value2 = ws1.Cells(i, "Q").Value2

                'year
                ws2.Cells(row_current, "I").Value2 = ws1.Cells(employee_name_row, "L").Value2

                row_current = row_current + 1

            End If

        ElseIf InStr(ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2, "Name") > 0 Then
            employee_name_row = i
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: For some reason it only pastes data for the "Cleaning" and "Scrubbing" activities and does not pick up "Mopping", "Wiping", "other" etc. Do you have any idea why? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @JohansonSimmons turns out I messed a few columns up because of the really small font! Hopefully this time i got it right

Comment: Is there anyway that I could email you the file/ send you the file somehow so that you could take a look for yourself? Unfortunately now it is only picking up the "Cleaning activity". Thanks :)

Comment: @JohansonSimmons Dangit! I'd appreciate if you could comment a link to a picture of how it is looking

Comment: I hope that link worked. Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @JohansonSimmons oh! haha just a bit of faulty logic it seems - instead of if-elseif-elseif ... they shouldve each been separate if's

Comment: @JohansonSimmons it also looks like it's not getting the year when it runs through. Is they year not in column M? It's hard to tell without gridlines.

Comment: [IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/16h85eu.png[/IMG] Please let me know if you can see the gridlines any better in this photo!

Comment: The year is actually in columns L and M, the "Cleaning" activity is in columns B3-D3, "Mopping" E3-G3, "Scrubbing" in H3-J3, "Wiping" in K3-M3

Comment: "Jumping" is in N3, "Swimming" in O3, "Other" in P3, and "Computer Problems" in Q3

Comment: This is my first time using this site so I unfortunately do not have enough "points" to start a private chat with you haha. Please feel free to email me at raymond88smith@gmail.com or text me at 240-695-6575

Comment: @JohansonSimmons actually stackoverflow does not have private messaging. Also, I know it's a bit cumbersome, but I would prefer to keep the messages on this site. btw i also added support for those other columns you mentioned :)

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. For some reason it will not pick up "Jumping", "Swimming", "Other", or "Computer problems". It displays the correct amount of hours performed on each, but will not display the titles of each activity under the "task" tab. Mopping, cleaning, scrubbing, and wiping work perfectly though :)

Comment: @JohansonSimmons the good news - it was an easy fix. the bad news - i think i'm losing my mind to make such goofy mistakes hahaha